# Error while installing Devstack on Ubuntu : "/opt/stack/requirements/.venv/bin/pip" not exists

Tags: python, ubuntu, openstack, devstack

While trying to install devstack, I got this error saying:

```
+inc/python:pip_install:359 env http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= PIP_FIND_LINKS= SETUPTOOLS_SYS_PATH_TECHNIQUE=rewrite /opt/stack/requirements/.venv/bin/pip install -c /opt/stack/requirements/up
per-constraints.txt -U pbr
env: ‘/opt/stack/requirements/.venv/bin/pip’: No such file or directory
+inc/python:pip_install:1 exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:515 local r=127
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:516 jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:516 jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:519 [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:525 '[' -f '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:530 kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:425 '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:532 [[ 127 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:533 echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:535 type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:536 generate-subunit 1536645760 69 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:538 [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:541 /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:550 exit 127
```

It looks like I am unable to install pip in the virtualenv of devstack. I tried `virtualenv` command in the `requirements` directory but unfortunately the error persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying many solutions which did not work. I finally got it working.

The actual error is that devstack is unable to create a virtual environment for itself because it does not have access to some file in `.cache` directory. Unfortunately, this error will only pop up the first time you are trying to install devstack.

I followed these steps:

`sudo chown -R stack:stack .cache/
virtualenv requirements/` 
At this point, you should have `pip` in your `.cache` directory.

The next step is to remove everything except `/devstack` and `.cache` directories and run 
`cd devstack/
./clean.sh`

Finally, run 
`./stack.sh`

PS : the aim is to set up `virtual environment` for `devstack`. You may choose your way of doing it.